# Use zendframework 1 library in zendframework 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, matomo

I am newbie for Zend and as well for [Piwik.](http://piwik.org/) I want to use [piwik library for zend](https://github.com/daFish/Zend_Service_Piwik) into my ZF2 application.

But the problem is [piwik library for zend](https://github.com/daFish/Zend_Service_Piwik) is built in ZF1 and my application is in ZF2.

I have check [this](http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/12/04/zend-framework-2-using-zend-framework-1-libraries-in-zend-framework-2/) solution to use ZF1 library in ZF2 but it is not working for me.

My **init_autoloader.php** is slightly different within the `if($zf2Path){ statement:`

```
if ($zf2Path && !class_exists('Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory')) {
    if (isset($loader)) {
        $loader->add('Zend', $zf2Path);
        $loader->add('ZendXml', $zf2Path);      
    } else {
        include $zf2Path . '/Zend/Loader/AutoloaderFactory.php';
        Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory::factory(array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'autoregister_zf' => true,
            )
        ));
    }
}
```

and I have changed `if($zf2Path){ statement:` part of **init_autoloader.php** like this

```
if ($zf2Path && !class_exists('Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory')) {
    if (isset($loader)) {
        $loader->add('Zend', $zf2Path);
        $loader->add('ZendXml', $zf2Path);
    } else {
        include $zf2Path . '/Zend/Loader/AutoloaderFactory.php';

        set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array($zf1Path, get_include_path())));
        Zend\Loader\AutoloaderFactory::factory(array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'autoregister_zf' => true,
                'prefixes' => array(
                    'Zend_' => $zf1Path . '/Zend'
                ),
            )
        ));
    }
}
```

So can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Zend Framework 2 integration here: https://github.com/heiglandreas/piwik